# pod with pvc stuck on container creating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, azure-disk

My overall issue is that my pod which has a PVC is stuck on container-creating after it was deleted. My guess why, is because of the following:

So, I have a pod with a mounted PVC. I did a:
`kubectl exec -it "name" bash`
navigated to the path of the mounted PVC and wanted to create a tar gzip file of several directories. The reason was because I wanted to copy the folders to local, but they were quite big. Anyways, managed to create the tar file, but someone else released to our dev environment and the pod was killed. After that, when recreating our env, the pod with the PVC that has the tar file is stuck on container creating. Is it because that I created that file on the PVC? Like, based on the warnings it seems like the PVC points to the previous pod?

```
kubectl get pvc

NAME           STATUS   VOLUME CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
graphite-pvc   Bound    xxxx   256Gi      RWO            managed-premium   12
```

and if I do, i get the following warnings:

```
kubectl describe pod xxx
```

Warning  FailedAttachVolume  22m (x8 over 24m)   attachdetach-controller
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-f65cb358-014b-11ea-b698-000d3a556597" : Attach volume "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-f65cb358-014b-11ea-b698-000d3a556597" to instance "/subscriptions/1405bf18-bf7d-4a2f-9aa7-25ff73ba58a6/resourceGroups/cie-dev-2-1-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/k8s-dev-nodes-2002/virtualMachines/6" failed with compute.VirtualMachineScaleSetVMsClient#Update: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status= Code="ConflictingUserInput" Message="Disk '/subscriptions/1405bf18-bf7d-4a2f-9aa7-25ff73ba58a6/resourceGroups/cie-dev-2-1-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-f65cb358-014b-11ea-b698-000d3a556597' cannot be attached as the disk is already owned by VM '/subscriptions/1405bf18-bf7d-4a2f-9aa7-25ff73ba58a6/resourceGroups/cie-dev-2-1-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/k8s-dev-nodes-2002/virtualMachines/k8s-dev-nodes-2002_111'."

and

Warning  FailedMount         48s (x13 over 28m)  kubelet, k8s-dev-nodes-2002000006  Unable to mount volumes for pod "xxxx": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "xxxxxx". list of unmounted volumes=[pvc_name]. list of unattached volumes=[pvc_name default-token-6tmkm]

So, first, do you think it has any correlation with the fact that I was inside the PVC and created a file, when the pod was killed, or is it pure coincidence (cannot be, right?).

Comment: I don't think there is any correlation. To resolve your issue I suggest manually detaching disk from vm `k8s-dev-nodes-2002_111`, k8s will then try to attach it and hopefully succeeds.

Comment: Okay, but is it something that just happens? I mean, this would be quite a big issue if this was the prod environment. I will try to detach it, unfortunately in this company it is another team who's in charge of our Kubernetes clusters, so just wanted to make sure it could be solved that way, before I contact others.

Comment: I happens sometimes. I have found [this article](https://portworx.com/understand-resolve-warning-failed-attach-volume-warning-failed-mount-errors-kubernetes-azure/), maybe you will find it useful as it explains some of this errors and how to deal with them

Comment: Alright, I asked them to detach it, so now we will see if that helps. I'll keep you updated. Thanks for the article!